# EventLogQuery not pulling results

Tags: c#

Edit: ok I know the query is incorrect. When I remove the TimeCreated part I get results back. What is the proper way to pull all events for that given day?

```
startTime = DateTime.Now.Date

string query = "*[System/Level=1 or System/Level=2] and TimeCreated[@SystemTime >= '" + startTime + "']";
using (EventLogSession session = new EventLogSession(serverName))
{
    EventLogQuery eventQuery = new EventLogQuery(logName, PathType.LogName, query);
    eventQuery.Session = session;

    using (EventLogReader reader = new EventLogReader(eventQuery))
    {
        for (EventRecord eventDetail = reader.ReadEvent(); eventDetail != null; eventDetail = reader.ReadEvent())
        {
            entries.Add(eventDetail);
        }
    }
}
```

I have tired the following as well

```
"*[System/Level=1 or System/Level=2] and *[System/TimeCreated[@SystemTime >= '" + startTime + "']]";

"*[System[(Level=1) or System[(Level=2)] and TimeCreated[@SystemTime >= '" + startTime.ToUniversalTime().ToString("o") + "']]";
```

Comment: You can test your query directly in the windows event viewer dialog box. You can parametrized it and then get the corresponding query. I'll post an helper I've made for one of my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I made a helper to retrieve log from the event viewer, you can parametrized it quite easily

```
public static void WriteEventViewerHistoryByTypes(IList<EventViewerCriticalityLevel> levelTypes, string logType, string filePath, IList<string> sources, DateTime? startDate = new System.Nullable<DateTime>(), DateTime? endDate = new System.Nullable<DateTime>())
    {
        if (levelTypes == null || levelTypes.Count == 0)
            levelTypes = new List<EventViewerCriticalityLevel> { EventViewerCriticalityLevel.Comment, EventViewerCriticalityLevel.Error, EventViewerCriticalityLevel.Fatal, EventViewerCriticalityLevel.Info, EventViewerCriticalityLevel.Warning };

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("<QueryList>");
        sb.AppendFormat("<Query Id=\"0\" Path=\"{0}\">", logType);
        sb.AppendFormat("   <Select Path=\"{0}\">", logType);
        sb.AppendFormat("   *[System[(");

        sb.AppendFormat("({0})", string.Join(" or ", levelTypes.Select(lev =>
           {

               if (lev == EventViewerCriticalityLevel.Info)
                   return string.Format("Level={0} or Level=0", (int)lev);
               else
                   return string.Format("Level={0}", (int)lev);
           })));

        if (sources != null && sources.Count > 0)
        {
            sb.AppendFormat(" or ");
            sb.AppendFormat("(Provider[{0}])", string.Join(" or ", sources.Select(el => "@Name='" + el + "'")));
        }
        sb.AppendFormat(")");
        if (startDate.HasValue)
        {
            sb.AppendFormat(" and TimeCreated[@SystemTime >= '{0}']", startDate.Value.ToString("o"));
        }
        if (endDate.HasValue)
        {
            sb.AppendFormat(" and TimeCreated[@SystemTime <= '{0}']", endDate.Value.ToString("o"));
        }
        sb.AppendFormat("]]");
        sb.AppendFormat("   </Select>");
        sb.AppendFormat("</Query>");
        sb.Append("</QueryList>");

        try
        {
            EventLogSession sess = new EventLogSession();
            sess.ExportLogAndMessages(logType, PathType.LogName, sb.ToString(), filePath, true, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

And here the enum

```
public enum EventViewerCriticalityLevel
{
    Fatal = 1,
    Error = 2,
    Warning = 3,
    Info = 4,
    Comment = 5
}
```

It will generate evtx files that you can read with the event viewer console.

Hope it helps !